# How to apt-get install package from different package source

Tags: ubuntu, pandas

I have ubuntu 14.04, I want to install 0.16.2 version of pandas, which seems to exists in this source https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-pandas.

I don't know how to install from this source.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install pandas` at the command line should get you 0.16.2.

If you want to `apt-get install` it though from a specific source (in this case a debian mirror), you'll first need to add the specific mirror to apt.  You should be able to add a [mirror](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/python-pandas/download) by adding a line to your /etc/apt/sources.list by entering this at the command line:

`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main`

Then, to specify a specific version, you can use the `=version` syntax of apt-get, like so:

`sudo apt-get install python-pandas=0.16.2+git65-g054821d-1`